# Modification in SAP cloud application

Tags: c#

I have an issue adding some code in SAP cloud application.
I have to retrieve the ID of the employee that creates an order in C4C and print it in a camp z (or "label") called CreatedECC. When an emp creates this order a form is created where you can see emp name, date, delivery status, creation date, created by, etc... here is where the label was added for me to retrieve the userID and print it. Im not sure if someone can help me with the code... there is so much i can share.
Im new to javascript (and SAP cloud app) so i dont entirely understand the code and that´s why i need help

**The code is:**

```
import ABSL;
import AP.CRM.Global;

var query_mapping;
var sel_param_mapping;
var result_mapping;

this.IsConsistent = true;
var i = 0;

foreach (var item in this.Item)
{
    if (!item.Plant.IsInitial())
    {
        item.Plant = item.Plant.ToUpperCase();
        query_mapping = Plants.QueryByElements;
        sel_param_mapping = query_mapping.CreateSelectionParams();
        sel_param_mapping.Add(query_mapping.PlantID, "I", "EQ", item.Plant);
        result_mapping = query_mapping.Execute(sel_param_mapping);

        if (!result_mapping.GetFirst().IsSet())
        {
            raise MsgNoFoundPlantID.Create("E", item.Plant);
            i = 1;
        }
    }
}

if (i == 1)
{
    this.IsConsistent = false;
}
```

I spoke with a partner via skype (i think he helped with the development) and he told me the steps i need to follow wich are:

1. Create the patch in the corresponding development.   **Done.**
2. Add a reference object and select the customizing camp that was created for you
3. Add your code so that a variable would be equal to  the value Context.GetCurrentIdentityUUID. Through that value you get the userID you need to print in the customizing camp... And that is all

Comment: Er... is this meant to be JavaScript?

Comment: Well i think so... its not?

Comment: Your code uses things JavaScript doesn't have.

Comment: Ok i asked... apparently its sharp or csharp... Could any one help me with that one?